# What could cause a garage door opener trolley to only travel a few inches?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I have an older (circa year 2000) Chamberlain belt-drive opener. Today the trolley has started misbehaving. It opened the door fine this morning, but now will only travel a few inches down from the "door up" position, then reverses itself back to the starting (door up) position.

What I've done:

- Disengaged the door from the opener/trolley, to verify it's not a binding or other kind of "sticking" problem. The door travels easily by hand. The trolley exhibits the same behavior with or without the door engaged.
- Triple-checked the obstruction sensors. The green indicators are not flashing, but when I place something in front of them, they immediately flash to indicate the obstruction. I also confirmed that the opener recognizes when there is an obstruction: it flashes the lights and doesn't even travel the short distance.
- Held the wall button controller pressed. Same behavior.
- Adjusted the down travel distance and force. Setting either to the max value has no impact on this odd behavior.
- Unplugged the opener for approximately 15 minutes. After plugging it back in, still exhibits the same behavior.
- Visually inspected the belt and trolley. There does not seem to be anything wrong with them, at least visually.

I'm willing to accept that a nearly 20-year-old unit may have met its end, but I'd like to exhaust all DIY troubleshooting before either buying a new one or paying for a professional service call (which seems likely to result in a replacement anyway).

Comment: Check where the motor shaft connects to the gear sprocket. There is a roll pin in there that could have broke. Also, check for worn gear or belt. Sometimes the belt looks fine but is worn enough to not grab the gear. Check the limit switches that control length of travel.

Comment: i would look for something in the chain at the spot where it stops and reverses.

Comment: You have done everything but verify the drive coupling from the motor or pulley to sprocket. Like @jack suggests.

Comment: Pull the cover and inspect the travel adjustment mechanism. Just look at the adjustment screw and follow what it adjusts and you'll find the gears. These gears can get stripped, they're cheap and not too difficult to replace.